# pandas apply split and concatenation using lambda in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with the values like below.

```
apple~fruit lion~animal banana-fruit samsung~phone
```

Each item separated by `space(' ')` and every item and category separated by `'~'`. I want to extract each item name separated by space like below

```
apple lion banana samsung
```

I can get the first item of the value by using lambda. But I don't know how to concatenate each and every item separated by `space(' ')`.

```
df.item = df.item.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0].split('~')[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `join`, also `split` by default working with whitespace, so should be simplify:

```
df.item = df.item.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()[0].split('~')[0]))
```

solution with pandas text functions:

```
df.item = df.item.str.split().str[0].str.split('~').str[0].str.join(' ')
```

If performance is important use list comprehension:

```
df.item = [ ' '.join(x.split()[0].split('~')[0]) for x in df.item]
```

Comment: @SmithDwayne - Do you think missing value `NaN`? Then use second solution or `mask = df.item.notnull()` and `df.loc[mask, 'item'] = df.loc[mask, 'item'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()[0].split('~')[0]))`